# Difference between cast used in Compound literals and that done on a pointer variable?

Tags: c, compound-literals

Consider the following code:

```
int main()
{ 
    int *p;

    ++((int){5});    //compile without err/warning
    &((int){5});     //compile without err/warning

    ++((char *)p);   //Compile-time err: invalid lvalue in increment
    &((char *)p);    //Compile-time err: invalid lvalue in unary '&'

}
```

Why do the Compound Literals do not generate errors here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because the "cast" in a compound literal is not a cast at all - it just looks like one.

A compound literal (which is the complete construction `(int){5}`) creates an lvalue.  However a cast operator creates only an rvalue, just like most other operators.

This example would be allowed (but useless, just like your `int` examples):

```
++((char *){(char *)p});
&((char *){(char *)p});
```

Answer (score 4):

Compound literal doesn't have a *cast* in it. The `(int)` part of your compound literals is not a cast. It is just a type part of compound literal syntax. So, the question in this case is whether a compound literal is an object, an lvalue. The answer is yes, a compound literal is an lvalue. For this reason you can apply any operators to it that require an lvalue (like `++` or `&`).

The second part of your example contains casts. The result of a cast is always an rvalue. You can't use `++` and `&` with rvalues.

Answer (score 1):

The "cast" in a compound literal is actually **not** a *cast*, rather it is the *type* of the compound literal.
So, `(int){5}` is indeed more like an anonymous `int`, hence a valid `lvalue` which can be used anywhere an object of the same *type* (`int` in this case) could be used.

Whereas, `(char *)p` is actually a *cast* (`rvalue`), so it cannot be incremented `++` or referenced `&`.

Read [Dr.Doobs's in-depth article](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/184401404) about compound literals.